# Have repetitive table, need to compile

Tags: compile, extract

I have a simple repetitive 2-column table with the following structure (here columns are separated by comma, but in my file they are tab separated:

Unique_Identifier_1 ,
Data_typeA , Data_A1
Data_typeB , Data_B1
Data_typeC , Data_C1
Unique_Identifier_2 ,
Data_typeA , Data_A2
Data_typeB , Data_B2
Data_typeC , Data_C2

I would like to compile the contents of this table into a new table with the following more condensed format:

, Unique_Identifier_1, Unique_Identifier_2
Data_typeA , Data_A1 , Data_A2
Data_typeB , Data_B1 , Data_B2
Data_typeC , Data_C1 , Data_C2

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an excel command, "OFFSET":

=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-2)*8+INT((COLUMN()-4)),0)

This prints data from a table starting at A1, into a new table as follows:

"ROW()-2" indicates offset two rows down from A1, or Row 3.

"*8" indicates that the original table has 8 rows, so this action should be repeated every 8 rows.

"+INT((COLUMN()-4)" indicates offset four columns right of A1, or Column D.

",0" indicates that the original table has only one column, so the action is not repeated.

Then I copied this formula to the right 8 columns, then copied down until all data were printed to the new table.

That is my working solution and current understanding of this excel function. I spot checked an enormous table and all data were where they should be. As I use this function more, I hope to gain a better understanding of it's utility.

Thank you to those of who took the time to read my question. I am sure there is a better solution using grep, sed, awk or list, but I don't know how yet. I am hoping to move beyond excel soon. I searched for a non-excel solution, but I don't have the experience necessary to come up with adequate google search terms.

Comment: I'd you have tables then Excel is a pretty good solution. Maybe you could also try VLOOKUP, that's more error proof than OFFSET. If the data is arranged so you could solve your problem with OFFSET, then you could even copied last column of table top other column.